# AWS Lambda Python : Access denied while calling Copy object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am new to this Aws & python just started to learn when I execute the following code in AWS Lambda I am getting the `copyobject access denied` error.

```py
    import boto3
    import json

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


    def lambda_handler(event, context):
         dest_bucket = s3.Bucket('knlambdadestbucket')
         source_bucket = s3.Bucket('knlambdasourcebucket')
      
    
    for obj in source_bucket.objects.all():
        dest_key = obj.key
        print(dest_key)
        s3.Object(dest_bucket.name, dest_key).copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket': 
       obj.bucket_name, 'Key': obj.key} )
```

When I execute the above code in AWS Lambda, I am getting this error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied

I created the policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdasourcebucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdadestbucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any tool to debug the Lambda code?

Answer (score 1):

In the Bucket policy, when specifying a Bucket:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdasourcebucket"
```

add a wild card to the end:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdasourcebucket/*"
```

This is required for **object-level operations** such as `GetObject` and `PutObject`.

**Bucket-level operations** such as `ListBucket` require the ARN of the bucket *without* a wildcard.

The result is:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdasourcebucket",
              "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdasourcebucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::knlambdadestbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```